# Installing and Managing Jenkins on Amazon Linux

Tags: amazon-ec2, jenkins

I'm looking to move Jenkins to Amazon EC2 running Amazon Linux.

Currently we have Jenkins installed as a package (via `yum`). I'm considering running Jenkins as the contained `jenkins.war` on EC2 (for auto-upgrades and ease of deployment).

Unfortunately I've been unable to find much documentation regarding managing jenkins as the latter.

I'm trying to determine:

- Which installation is preferred, and why?
- If running as a contained jar:

  - How do I start/stop jenkins?
  - Should I create a jenkins user?

Answer (score 30):

Installation Steps :

1. Please launch an Amazon Linux instance using Amazon Linux AMI.
2. Login to your Amazon Linux instance.
3. Become root using “**sudo su -**” command.
4. Update your repositories

   **yum update**
5. Get Jenkins repository using below command

   **wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/jenkins.repo http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/redhat-stable/jenkins.repo**
6. Get Jenkins repository key

   **rpm --import http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/redhat-stable/jenkins-ci.org.key**
7. Install jenkins package

   **yum install jenkins**
8. Start jenkins and make sure it starts automatically at system startup

   **service jenkins start**

   **chkconfig jenkins on**
9. Open your browser and navigate to `http://<Elastic-IP>:8080`. You will see jenkins dashboard.

That’s it. You have your jenkins setup up and running. Now, you can create jobs to build the code.

Reference: http://sanketdangi.com/post/62715793234/install-configure-jenkins-on-amazon-linux

Comment: While your copy/paste  from http://sanketdangi.com/post/62715793234/install-configure-jenkins-on-amazon-linux is thorough, it doesn't really answer the question, as OP was asking for advice, not instructions.

Comment: thanks, I appreciate the instructions.  I do hope someone chimes in on rpm vs war.  Is it possible to update the war if installed via rpm?

Comment: +1 for the copy & paste of http://sanketdangi.com/post/62715793234/install-configure-jenkins-on-amazon-linux as that page is not coming up right now, although you should attribute your source if you really did copy and paste.

Comment: this assumes the JDK is already installed, if its not you will get an error during startup: "Job for jenkins.service failed because the control process exited with error code." install java with "yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel"

Comment: Thanks. This should be marked as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins Installation **Ubuntu 14.04/16.01**
Please follow the steps given below. 
Switch to root user **sudo su -**

1. sudo apt-get update
2. sudo apt-get install default-jdk
3. sudo apt-get install default-jre
4. wget -q -O - https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian/jenkins-ci.org.key | sudo apt-key add -
5. echo deb https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jenkins.list
6. sudo apt-get update
7. apt-get install jenkins
8. Get jenkins Password from:-   vi /var/lib/jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword
   Browse:- eg:  192.168.xx.xx:8080